# The new Marker is not being shown in map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, hashmap

I have a checkboxlist where the user can select some routes then a reponse is being getting from the server. I have method `gotoLocation` to upadte  the location of the markers as well  to add a new marker in the map
 when a new one is being inserted into the table on the serverside with the same route.

I am using HashMap with **the table id as a  key** and the marker as value also in my case the key is `unique`.

The Updating part works fine but I am facing problem with the **adding part**. So after the user selectes the desired routes, they are being added to the map  as marker and to the HashMap as elements but the problem occures when I insert a new one with the same route and different key (id is being incremented by one in the table) into the table then the adding part is being entered and the id of the new added one is being recognized but the new marker is not being added on the map but **to the  HashMap markerMap**.

Additionally when the new Response reaches the method again I noticed that the last added marker with the new id is not in the HashMap and it just contains the elements of the first request also when the request is over and the new added element stays in the HashMap for the request Life! is there any explanation for this behaviour and how can I fix it?

**Code:**

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap map;
    HashMap<Integer, Marker> markerMap = new HashMap<Integer, Marker>();
    Marker marker = null;

    private void gotoLocation(int id, double lat, double lng,
            String route_direct) {
        // check = false;

        final float zoom = 11;
        LatLng ll = null;

        if (markerMap.containsKey(id)) {
            //Update block.
            // Update the location.

            // To figure out which ones was not updated.
            idList.add(id);

            marker = markerMap.get(id);
            // Remove from the map fragment.
            marker.remove();
            // Remove from the HashMap tp add the new one.
            markerMap.remove(id);

            ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            if (lat != 0 && lng != 0 && !route_direct.isEmpty()) {
                MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(route_direct).position(ll).visible(true);
                marker = map.addMarker(markerOpt);
                markerMap.put(id, marker);

                CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll,
                        zoom);
                map.moveCamera(update);
            }

        } else {
            //Add block.
            // Add the marker on the map in the case it does not exist in the
            // HashMap before.
            ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            if (lat != 0 && lng != 0 && !route_direct.isEmpty()) {
                MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(route_direct).position(ll).visible(true);
                marker = map.addMarker(markerOpt);
                //Here when I add a new record to my table then it is being added to the HashMap but this block is being always entered since the new added one stays in the markerMap for the request life and is not as the added content of the first request.
                markerMap.put(id, marker);

                CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll,
                        zoom);
                map.moveCamera(update);
            }

        }

    }
```

**Edit**

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap map;
    HashMap<Integer, String> markerMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    static String marker_string;

    static Marker marker = null;
    private void gotoLocation(int id, double lat, double lng,
            String route_direct) {
        final float zoom = 11;
        LatLng ll = null;
        if (markerMap.containsKey(id)) {
            // Update the location.
            marker_string = markerMap.get(id);              
            String[] marker_string_split = marker_string.split(",");
            double latit = Double.parseDouble(marker_string_split[0]);
            double longit = Double.parseDouble(marker_string_split[1]);
            String rout_dirc = marker_string_split[2];

            LatLng LL_2 = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            MarkerOptions markerOpt2 = new MarkerOptions().title(route_direct)
                    .position(LL_2);

            // This here doest work.
            marker.remove();

            // Remove from the HashMap tp add the new one.
            markerMap.remove(id);

            ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions().title(route_direct)
                    .position(ll);
            marker = map.addMarker(markerOpt);

            String lat1 = Double.toString(lat);
            String lng1 = Double.toString(lng);
            String data = lat1 + "," + lng1 + "," + route_direct;
            markerMap.put(id, data);
            zoom();

        } else {
            // Add a new  marker 
            String lat1 = Double.toString(lat);
            String lng1 = Double.toString(lng);
            String data = lat1 + "," + lng1 + "," + route_direct;
            markerMap.put(id, data);

            ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions().title(route_direct)
                    .position(ll);
            marker = map.addMarker(markerOpt);
            zoom();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It could be problem with trying to store markers in the hashmap. Maybe you can try storing just the lat/long in string format into the hashmap with id to retrieve for later user, instead of marker object itself.

Comment: The problem might be that you're trying to add a Marker at a location where there is already a Marker on the Map, and it gets "doubled-up".  Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704124/how-to-handle-multiple-markers-on-google-maps-with-same-location

Comment: @DanielNugent: I am inserting longitude and latitiude into the table which are far away of the existing markers in the map.

Comment: @so_jin_ee: I have tried your Point and it works for me thanks :)

Comment: @DanielNugent: I have concatenated the latit, Longit and the direction to String add added them as a value to the HashMap adding block works now but I dont know how can I remove the old one from the map in the updating block since I do not have marker in the HashMap and I can't use `marker.remove()`.  How can I convert the String to Marker to delete the old one of the map?

Comment: I noticed after inserting a new data for a route in the table the new marker is being added to the map but the `else block` is still being entered every time also it does  acknowledge that it added the last `id` before.

Comment: @MrPencil I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what your issue is, but just to let you know, I tested your original code in this question with a simple isolated test, and it worked for me.  I tested with five different IDs, and it got into the `else` block and added Markers every time.  It sounds like your real issue is not in this code, but elsewhere in your code.