# How to handle more than one location on the same address and cluster them?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google maps with clusters in iOS application developed in Swift. On google map there are some markers with the same latitude and longitude. When user zooms in to the point where are only two places in cluster and zooms a little bit more when markers are shown, these markers are glitched (flickering) and they overlay rapidly each other (one over another).

How can I accomplish when user zooms in, and there are only two markers in cluster with same address and location, to not split them out of cluster into markers, so that they stay clustered? Is there a way to get markers from (that are in) the cluster Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue , to overcome flashing effect it had given very minor variation to similar values of latitude and longitude.

```
func checkIfMutlipleCoordinates(latitude : Float , longitude : Float) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D{

        var lat = latitude
        var lng = longitude

        // arrFilterData is array of model which is giving lat long

        let arrTemp = self.arrFilteredData.filter {

            return (((latitude == $0.latitute) && (longitude == $0.longitute)))
        }

        // arrTemp giving array of objects with similar lat long 

        if arrTemp.count > 1{
            // Core Logic giving minor variation to similar lat long

            let variation = (randomFloat(min: 0.0, max: 2.0) - 0.5) / 1500
            lat = lat + variation
            lng = lng + variation
        }
        let finalPos = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(lat), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(lng))
        return  finalPos
    }

 func randomFloat(min: Float, max:Float) -> Float {
        return (Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF) * (max - min) + min
    }
```

Simply call `checkIfMutlipleCoordinates` whenever you set marker position

```
 let position = checkIfMutlipleCoordinates(latitude: yourlatitute!, longitude: yourlongitute!)
```

Comment: I thought of this approach but, I cannot change location as I am bound with a feature limitation.
Nice approach.

Comment: We are not changing latitude and longitude here , just giving a minor variation for showing markers on map. The actual data i.e. location will remain same. I just did so to overcome flashing effect.

Comment: Yup, I understand \m/

Comment: Yes, this is a good approach, but I need to show locations with the same latitude and longitude as a cluster regardless of zoom level. Rather than as markers.

Comment: You need to design custom layout for the same. Just show the first or last marker and on tap you can show cluster

Comment: let variation = (randomFloat(min: 0.0, max: 2.0) - 0.5) / 15000

Comment: @ArpitJain I still need close variation for same lat long. Can you please let me know which thing i need to change in your variation equation.

Answer (score 5):

I am sorry to be late for the party but: 
as of version 1.4.0(July 2013) of the SDK there's a property on GMSOverlay(Which GMSMarker subclasses) named 'zIndex'.

As stated in the docs:

> Higher zIndex value overlays will be drawn on top of lower zIndex
>   value tile layers and overlays.
>
> Equal values result in undefined draw ordering.

The flickering might be because both markers have zIndex == 0

Anyways, that's what worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

**Known behavior of Google Maps iOS SDK**

If you are creating a custom marker and using the iconView property to change an image of the icon it will give a flashing effect if the coordinates are completely same.It is a known issue of google maps iOS SDK.Try using default marker's instead and see if an issue is persisting.

Comment: Yes I'm working with custom markers and I'm using iconView property. Ok, so there is the problem. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I had the same case , and i have managed it . Check my answer

Answer (score 2):

I recently faced this issue of multiple happenings on same latitude and longitude. I believe changing minor in latitude and longitude is an alternative but this may violate your business model if you are making a very specific location based application.

One solution is having a callout like view where you can list your multiple happenings when you tap on marker. Keep a custom image of marker with some badge number on top right(preferably) and on tapping the marker, show a callout.

You can refer the screenshot.

[image]

Something like this if this place has multiple happenings. You can just show any one happening and then on tap of marker you can show a callout of other happenings. You can make a callout by using a tableView or something.

Hope you get some idea.

[image]

Comment: I already did that, but when map is zoomed in the markers are still flickered.

Comment: Marker will never flicker even if you zoom the map.You just have to add only one and only one iconView for a lat long.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Swift 4 solution extending the CLLocationCoordinate2D based on Arpit Jain answer:

```
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    mutating func variateForEqual(coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]) {
        var variatedLatitude = latitude
        var variatedLongitude = longitude

        let filteredPositions = coordinates.filter {
            $0 == self
        }

        if filteredPositions.isNotEmpty {
            let variation = Double.random(in: -0.01...0.01) / 1500
            variatedLatitude = latitude + variation
            variatedLongitude = longitude + variation
        }

        self = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: variatedLatitude, longitude: variatedLongitude)
    }
}
`
```