# Multiple markers at same location?

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, google-maps-markers, location-services

I am developing an application which gets locations from `Firebase` by `GeoQuery` and it is showing markers on each location that is fetched by GeoQuery. But the problem is that if the location's latitude and longitude are the same, markers are overlapping each other and only one marker is shown. But I want to show multiple markers with same location.

I am fetching location from firebase and showing markers as:

```
GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),
                    mLastLocation.getLongitude()), 3);
            geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.latitude,location.longitude);
                    markerOptions.position(latLng);

                    try {
                        markerOptions.icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_marker));
                    } catch (Exception ex){}
                    mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyExited(String key) {}

                @Override
                public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {}

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryReady() {}

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {}
            });
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}
```

Comment: if the location's latitude and longitude is same it will mark in the same area so one will see

Comment: How about adding a number on Single Marker? For the sake of user awareness?

Comment: Yup, you are right. But I want to multiple markers.

Comment: @Sha-Dow what about using a cluster?

Comment: If you really want markers and make them distinguishable, you need to set them apart using a very small offset.

Comment: What is clusters ? @Debdeep

Comment: From this link, run the app and check the custom clustering example : https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils  or you may want to also make separate markers as I mentioned above.

Comment: Any example available of using offset to apart markers ? @Debdeep

Comment: Sure, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19945754/5685358